# Select2 set wrong value to option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I want to load form select options with jquery select2:

```
$('.select-with-search').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    ajax: {
        url: '/manager/ajax-get-values/',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "GET",
        data: function (params) {
          var query = {
            query: params.term,
            model: matchingModel
          }
          return query;
        }
    }
})
```

It works but when I try to choose any loaded option in select, it gets a wrong value (id instead text):

```html
<select class="select-with-search" data-select2-id="1">
  <option value="" data-select2-id="2">---</option>
  <option value="0" data-select2-id="254">ABC</option> <!-- Value is 0, but I want ABC -->
</select>
```

Example of ajax returned data:

```
{results: [
  {id: 0, text: "AAA" },
  {id: 1, text: "AAB" },
  {id: 2, text: "ABB" }
]}
```

Comment: can you edit your post and add the small part of the ajax fetched content ?

Comment: Do you want **text value or id?**

Comment: @jishansiddique I want to put text value in option value attr

Comment: @SimonDehaut done

Comment: once you receive the data (`results:[...]`) you can remap it as follow : `data.results = data.results.map( ({id, text}) => ({oldId:id, id:text}) );` but post your full code if it does't work

Comment: I do this: `processResults: function (data) {var r = []; for(var i = 0; data['results'].length > i; i++){r.push({id: data['results'][i].text, text: data['results'][i].text})}; return {"results": r}}` and it's work